# Ordenar por numeração SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela com as colunas `ID` e `ReqNorma` preenchidas com um seguinte padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo a *query* para filtra-las, recebo valores que não estão em ordem pois algumas delas foram cadastradas fora de ordem:

```
select Id,ReqNorma 
from TABLE 
where Norma = 'ISO 9001' 
ORDER BY ReqNorma
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer esse filtro ORDER BY para mostrar os resultados numericamente?

Comment: não seria só ordenar pelo id?

Comment: Qual o seu `SGBD`?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você precisa de uma ordenação numérica, e não alfanumérica, pelo prefixo da string contida no campo ReqNorma. Talvez um ORDER BY left(ReqNorma, position(' ' in ReqNorma))::numeric possa resolver, dependendo do SGBD que estiver utilizando. Talvez você também precise remover os '.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não me parece uma solução muito bonita, mas testei aqui e aparentemente funcionou.

```
select Id,ReqNorma 
from TABLE 
where Norma = 'ISO 9001' 
ORDER BY CAST( SUBSTRING(ReqNorma, 1, charindex('.', ReqNorma) -1) AS INT), ReqNorma
```

Explicação:

**charindex('.', ReqNorma) -1)**

Obtém o index do primeiro '.'

**SUBSTRING( ReqNorma, 1, [expressão anterior] )**

Pega a parte da string equivalente ao início até o primeiro '.'

Exemplo:

- 10.2 viraria 10
- 2.1 viraria 2
- 4.0 viraria 4

**CAST( [expressão anterior] as int)**:

Converte o valor retornado para inteiro, para que a ordenação seja numérica em vez de alfanumérica.

Comment: Aparentemente funciona sim, porém seria interessante você melhorar a qualidade de sua resposta para que outras pessoas possam entender o que você está fazendo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, vou editar agora mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Tente a seguinte consulta e verifique se é a ordenação desejada:

```
select Id,ReqNorma 
from TABLE 
where Norma = 'ISO 9001' 
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: Sua query ordena pelo `Id`, pela pergunta ele quer que ordene pelo número que está no início do ReqNorma.
Ex: Imagina que foram cadastrados a norma 1.0, em seguida a 1.1, depois a 2.0 e finalmente a 1.2. Ordenando por Id, ficaria "1.0; 1.1; 2.0; 1.2", mas na verdade ele quer "1.0; 1.1; 1.2; 2.0"

Comment: Me ajudou a ordenar os demais itens fora de ordem, mas os itens 10.1, 10.2 e 10.3 continuam aparecendo em primeiro lugar na filtragem. OBS: Filtrando pelo ReqNorma

Comment: Pra essa ordenação, apenas o order by não vai resolver. O ideal é separar esses campos, deixando uma coluna numérica para ordenação e outra de texto para a descrição. Tem comandos SQL que ajudam, como o SUBSTRING e o REPLACE, você pode fazer todo o ajuste com um update aninhado em um select usando esses comandos....

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que Intendi você precisa da sequencia, use o DESC depois do order by

Exemplo;

```
 declare @TABLE  table(id int, Norma varchar(30), ReqNorma varchar(50))
 insert into @TABLE select 106, 'ISO 9001', '4.2 entendo as
 necessidades...' insert into @TABLE select 107, 'ISO 9001', '4.3
 Determinndo o escopo...' insert into @TABLE select 108, 'ISO 9001',
 '4.4 Sistema de Gestão...' insert into @TABLE select 109, 'ISO 9001',
 '5.1.1 Liderença e...'


 select Id,ReqNorma from @TABLE where Norma = 'ISO 9001' ORDER BY
 ReqNorma desc
```

Caso não seja isso entre com mais detalhes!